# hibernate.cfg.xml not found by Play Framework

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework-2.0

I am new to Play Framework. I am migrating a project from struts2 to Play that uses Hibernate for ORM. I have a singleton class called HibernateConfig that loads the hibernate configuration this is  where I get the following error.

```
 In C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\projectname\app\data\HibernateConfig.java at line 27. [HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found] 
   private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;


  private HibernateConfig (){}

23  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory ()
24  {

25      if (sessionFactory == null)
26      {

27          sessionFactory = new Configuration    ().configure().buildSessionFactory();
28          return sessionFactory;
29      }
30      else

 31         return sessionFactory;
  }
```

This is how my project structure look like:

> app -> controllers -> application controller class
> app -> models -> model classes
> app -> data -> HibernateConfig.java
> app -> views -> html files
> app -> hibernate.cfg.xml

application.conf

> ## Database configuration
>
> db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
> db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname"
> db.default.user=root
> db.default.password=""

I know that the problem is  hibernate.cfg.xml is not being located when I called new Configuration    ().configure().buildSessionFactory() but I don't know where it must be placed in Play to be accessed. (Could u guys also critic my approach and let me know if I'm going about this the wrong way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the hibernate.cfg.xml file to the root of the conf folder and that should solve the problem.